# java regex when pattern might not match

Tags: java

How would I go about executing a block of code if the pattern matches or execute another block of code if the pattern does not match?

```
String input = "abc";

final String mainRegex = "(.*?)(&!|&|==)";

final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(mainRegex).matcher(input);
```

I have tried

```
if(matcher1.matches())
{
    execute this block
}

else
{
    execute this block
}
```

But it always executes the `else` block. Even when the input is `a>b&!c<d`.

Comment: I'd suggest testing your regex with a tool like http://regexpal.com/. If the matcher keeps telling you that your input does not match the regex, it probably means that none of your input matches the regex.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct but your regular expression is wrong. It doesn't match either of your examples.

Perhaps you could try this regular expression instead:

```
final String mainRegex = "(.*?)(&!|&|==)(.*)";
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ybbKa)